# terraform multiple aws route53 alias records under locals

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-route53

I have a set of AliasRecords under terraform `locals` and wanted to map them under terraform's `resource "aws_route53_record"`  . Below is the locals value:

```
locals {
    AWSAliasRecordSets = [
              {
                  Name =  "api-dev.example.com.",
                  Type =  "A",
                  AliasTarget =  {
                      HostedZoneId =  "EXAMPLE",
                      DNSName =  "kjhskdjhf.cloudfront.net.",
                      EvaluateTargetHealth =  false
                  }
              },
              {
                  Name =  "api.example.com.",
                  Type =  "A",
                  AliasTarget =  {
                      HostedZoneId =  "EXAMPLE",
                      DNSName =  "jsdhgfjkdshf.cloudfront.net.",
                      EvaluateTargetHealth =  false
                  }
              }
    ]
}
```

What I am doing is :

```
locals {
    FlatAWSAliasRecordSets = merge([
    for idx, AWSAliasRecordSet in local.AWSAliasRecordSets:
      {
        for AliasTarget in AWSAliasRecordSet.AliasTarget:
            "${idx}-${AliasTarget}" => {
              HostedZoneId          =  AliasTarget["HostedZoneId"]
              DNSName               =  AliasTarget["DNSName"]
              EvaluateTargetHealth  =  AliasTarget["EvaluateTargetHealth"]
          }
      }
    ]...)
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "alias_records" {
  for_each = local.FlatAWSAliasRecordSets
  zone_id  = each.value["HostedZoneId"]
  name     = each.value["AliasTarget"].Name
  type     = each.value["AliasTarget"].Type

  alias {
    zone_id                = each.value["HostedZoneId"]
    name                   = each.value["AliasTarget"].Name
    evaluate_target_health = each.value["EvaluateTargetHealth"]
  }
}
```

and when pushing to AWS ( terraform apply), it fails with below error:

```
│   on main.tf line 508, in locals:
│  508:               EvaluateTargetHealth  =  AliasTarget["EvaluateTargetHealth"] 

│ This value does not have any indices.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `AWSAliasRecordSets` does not require flattening, as it is already flat. Thus you can go use regular `count` for it.

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "alias_records" {
  count    = length(local.AWSAliasRecordSets)
  zone_id  = local.AWSAliasRecordSets[count.index]["AliasTarget"].HostedZoneId
  name     = local.AWSAliasRecordSets[count.index].Name
  type     = local.AWSAliasRecordSets[count.index].Type

  alias {
    zone_id                = local.AWSAliasRecordSets[count.index]["AliasTarget"].HostedZoneId
    name                   = local.AWSAliasRecordSets[count.index].DNSName
    evaluate_target_health = each.value["AliasTarget"].EvaluateTargetHealth
  }
}
```

You also have to double check your use of `Name` and `DNSName`. Your current usage does not seem right to me, but this would be a new issue if this is really the case.

Comment: Got this error while running it:

│ Error: Call to unknown function
│ 
│   on main.tf line 504, in resource "aws_route53_record" "alias_records":
│  504:   count    = count(local.AWSAliasRecordSets)
│     ├────────────────
│     │ local.AWSAliasRecordSets is tuple with 2 elements
│ 
│ There is no function named "count".

Comment: @Ajayk Sorry, it should be `length`.